# Control width of IntervalMarkers in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, around

I am creating a scatter plot with error bars in Mathematica 12 using `IntervalMarkers -> "fences"`. Is there a simple way to increase the width of the top and bottom lines of the "fences" using `IntervalMarkersStyle`? Here is a simple example.

```
ListPlot[Around[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
  Transpose[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10], RandomReal[{1, 3}, 10]}],
 IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceStyle" -> Red, 
   "WhiskerStyle" -> Black|>]
```

For example, how do I make the red lines twice as wide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the suboption `"FenceWidth"`; for example,

```
IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceStyle" -> Red, 
   "FenceWidth"-> .5,
   "WhiskerStyle" -> Black|>
```

Comment: I just noticed I missed that in the documentation. Thanks!